# Display element if DOMs' scrollposition is greater then xyz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a fixed element if the users scroll position is greater then a certain height. So I tried to do this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 700px) {
        $('#trigger_lisa').css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

To explain it, if the users focus is greater then 700px I want to display the element `#trigger_lisa`. The way I did the "700px" is weird, but I have no clue on how to do better.

Thanks for helping

Comment: `scrollTop()` returns an int, so your condition should be just `if ($(document).scrollTop() > 700)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`700px` is a syntax error. `"700px"` would be valid but wrong. Just use `700`.

However, if you want to hide it again when the user scrolls back, use `toggle`:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  $('#trigger_lisa').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 700);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
#trigger_lisa {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger_lisa"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has incorrect notation, an "px" is not need for this case, "700" must be a number. In general case your code works:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop()>700)
    {
        $('#trigger_lisa').css("display","block");
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 3000px;
}
#trigger_lisa {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="trigger_lisa"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/p7bcjvm4/1/